# how i can send two or more than two arguments to private methods of class using properties

Tags: c#

hi i have class with one private method. i am trying to send two values(two arguments) to its method using property but its not working.some time it gives compiler error and some time wrong answer(logical error).

```
class sum
{
    private int add (int a, int b) 
    {
        return a+b;
    }

    private int ts;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return ts; }
        set { ts = add(value,value);
    }
}
```

Code in main Class

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sum sumv = new sum();
    sumv.MyProperty=2;

    int sumj = sumv.MyProperty;
    MessageBox.Show(sumj.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Your code works good. Can you specify your troubles?

Comment: Why not just make `add` public?

Comment: @artem actually i want to send him two different values like 2 and 3 and it should add them and generate sum 5 ; but i am not able to send him two values of my desire

Comment: @David i read from some where. public methods are not recommended approach and am also learning and practicing OOP concepts thats why i make it private

Comment: Why would a public method be bad?

Comment: @DavidG you can not add public method in class because This is not the recommended way to pass information over to your classes, though. Method are usually hidden from the outside world by making them private. This "hiding" methods and variables in your class is known as Encapsulation. The idea is that you hide as much of your class as possible. That way, it can't be broken by passing information over that the class can't handle. A broken class may crash your programme!

Comment: Where did you read that?! Anyway, your class is purely for adding two numbers together, so there's nothing to encapsulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the short answer is: you can't send two parameters to a property setter.

Properties are just meant to be synthaxical sugar to avoid having to implement java/c++-like accessors (getProperty(), setProperty()...).

That being said, you can totally do some work on the `value` you get in the property's setter (like checking if it is in a certain range of values, or even modifying it...). But `value` is the only value you will ever get by using it.

And public methods aren't inherently bad, else we wouldn't have the mean to use them in the first place. I'd like to know where you've seen that.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and i read this from a website from where i am learning c# and OOP concepts and That site is home and learn , am not sharing its link may be its not allowed here

Comment: You say something isn't bad *else we wouldn't have the mean to use them*, well C# still has `goto` in it, or you can remove all whitespace and have your entire app on one line of code.

Comment: Well, `goto` aren't BAD, they're just... yeah, I got your point. :p

Answer (score 0):

If you want to practice in OOP concepts - your way isn't correct.

This class much better suitable for OOP:

```
public class Adder
{
    public int Result {get; private set;}   // private setter allow you to hide this member.

    public void Sum(int value1, int value2)
    {
        Result = value1 + value2;
    } 
}
```

Comment: you added public method but This is not the recommended way to pass information over to your classes, though. Method are usually hidden from the outside world by making them private. This "hiding" methods and variables in your class is known as Encapsulation. The idea is that you hide as much of your class as possible. That way, it can't be broken by passing information over that the class can't handle. A broken class may crash your programme!

Comment: @junaid No no, you got it wrong! If, indeed, you just want to PASS a parameter to a property, you use the setter. but if you want to MODIFY its value with an algorithm, you have to use a method. This answer is completely valid OOP code. If you want to check if Result can handle the value it gets from Sum(), you do it in its setter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule of some sort about this :

> If you have private method that you want to expose to other classes
>   but you don't want to make it public then create a public delegate 
>   and pass your method with this delegate

Your property can be of delegate type. In this case the `get` method will return delegate. This delegates contains your method add, that you can run :

```
class sum
{
    private int add (int a, int b) 
    {
        return a+b;
    }

    public Func<int, int, int> MyProperty
    {
        get { return add; }
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sum sumv = new sum();

    int sumj = sumv.MyProperty(5, 10);
    MessageBox.Show(sumj.ToString());
}
```

Comment: A tad overkill, but interesting! :p

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of confusion here caused by OOP principles. Here's a couple of ways you could achieve what you want.

1. Make your method public. There's nothing wrong with doing this as you are not storing anything and there's nothing to encapsulate:

   ```
   public class Adder
   {
       public int Add(int value1, int value2)
       {
           return value1 + value2;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Pass in your parameters in the class constructor:

   ```
   public class Adder
   {
       private int _value1;
       private int _value2;

       public Adder(int value1, int value1)
       {
           _value1 = value1;
           _value3 = value2; 
       }

       public int Add()
       {
           return _value1 + _value2;
       }

   }
   ```